# Typing two letters at the same time causes docker exec -it shell to exit abruptly

Tags: shell, docker, docker-toolbox

I'm running Docker Toolbox on VirtualBox on Windows 10.

I'm having an annoying issue where if I `docker exec -it mycontainer sh` into a container - to inspect things, the shell will abruptly exit randomly back to the host shell, while I'm typing commands. Some experimenting reveals that it's when I press two letters at the same time (as is common when touch typing) that causes the exit.

The container will still be running.

Any ideas what this is?

**More details**

Here's a minimal docker image I'm running inside. Essentially, I'm trying to deploy kubernetes clusters to AWS via kops, but because I'm on Windows, I have to use a container to run the kops commands.

```
FROM alpine:3.5

#install aws-cli
RUN apk add --no-cache \
  bind-tools\
  python \
 python-dev \
 py-pip \
 curl


RUN pip install awscli 

#install kubectl
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl


#install kops
RUN curl -LO https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/releases/download/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kops/releases/latest | grep tag_name | cut -d '"' -f 4)/kops-linux-amd64
RUN chmod +x kops-linux-amd64
RUN mv kops-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/kops
```

I build this image:

```
docker build -t mykube .
```

I run this in the working directory of my the project I'm trying to deploy:

```
docker run -dit -v "${PWD}":/app mykube
```

I `exec` into the shell:

```
docker exec -it $containerid sh
```

Inside the shell, I start running AWS commands [as per here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kops/).

Here's some example output:

```
##output of previous dig command 
;; Query time: 343 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.3#53(10.0.2.3)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 14 21:32:16 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 188

##me entering a command
/ # aws s3 mb s3://clus
##shell exits abruptly to host shell while I'm writing
DavidJ@DavidJ-PC001 MINGW64 ~/git-workspace/webpack-react-express (master)
##container is still running 
$ docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
37a341cfde83        mykube              "/bin/sh"           5 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            gifted_bhaskara
##nothing in docker logs
$ docker logs --details 37a341cfde83
```

**A more useful update**

Adding the `-D` flag gives an important clue:

```
$ docker -D exec -it  04eef8107e91 sh -x
DEBU[0000] Error resize: Error response from daemon: no such exec
                                                                  / #
/ #
/ #
/ #
/ # sdfsdfjskfdDEBU[0006] [hijack] End of stdin
DEBU[0006] [hijack] End of stdout
```

Also, I've ascertained that what specifically is causing the issue is pressing two letters at the same time (which is quite common when I'm touch typing).

There appears to be a [github issue for this here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/934), though this one is for docker for windows, not docker toolbox.

Comment: Without a [mcve], it's not easy to say. That said, one thing short of a reproducer you could add is a [sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/) trace of what happens to the shell process -- that way we could see if it's getting a signal (and which one), being told its stdin is closing, or otherwise what else is happening. (Sysdig can be run from one container to monitor operations in another, making it a particularly appropriate diagnostic tool for this particular job).

Comment: (Putting a bounty on a vague question doesn't make it any more answerable, but it *does* bounce it up towards the top of the listing, make it impossible to close without moderator involvement, and generate a bunch of activity from people trying to guess despite the lack of actionable and useful details. If you actually want an *answer*, as opposed to *attention*, though, concrete steps towards a procedure tested to allow others to reproduce the issue themselves, or diagnostic logs, would be considerably more productive).

Comment: Are you sure the container is not failing and restarting? Because that's exactly what would happen. Does `docker ps --all` show a bunch of failed or exited containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue appears to be a bug with docker and windows. [See the github issue here.](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/934)

As a work around, prefix your `docker exec` command with winpty, which comes with git bash.

eg.

```
winpty docker exec -it mycontainer sh
```

Comment: Good feedback and nice catch. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check the `USER` which is the one you are login with when doing a `docker exec -it yourContainer sh`.
Its `.bahsrc`, `.bash_profile` or `.profile` might include a command which would explain why the session abruptly quits.

Check also the logs associated to that container ([`docker logs --details yourContainer`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/#options)) in order to see if that closed session generated anything in stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons I can think of for a process to be killed in your container include:

- Pid 1 exiting in the container. This would cause the container to go into a stopped state, but a restart policy could have restarted it. See your `docker container inspect` output to see if this is happening. This is the most common cause I've seen.
- Out of memory on the OS, where the kernel would then kill processes. View your system logs and dmesg to see if this is happening.
- Exceeding the container memory limit, where docker would kill the container, possibly restarting it depending on your policy. You would again view `docker container inspect` but the status will have different details.
- Process being killed on the host, potentially by a security tool.
- Perhaps a selinux or apparmor policy being violated.
- Networking issues. Never encountered it myself, but since docker is a client / server design, there's a potential for a network disconnect to drop the exec session.
- The server itself is failing, and you'd see various logs in syslog / dmesg indicating problems it can't recover from.